# Memcached started evicting items even when limit_maxbytes was not reached

Tags: linux, memory-management, memcached

I was running an application which was to load about 60 mil items in memcache. I had two servers added in a bucket. After about 65% of the data was loaded, I saw 1.3 mil items evicted in both servers. And these were statistics at that point.

**On server 1**

```
STAT bytes_written 619117542
STAT limit_maxbytes 3145728000
```

**On server 2**

```
STAT bytes_written 619118863
STAT limit_maxbytes 3145728000
```

Here's the output of `free -m` at that point of time.

**On server 1**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7987       5965       2021          0        310        441
-/+ buffers/cache:       5213       2774
Swap:         4095          0       4095
```

**On sever 2**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         11980      11873        106          0        207       5860
-/+ buffers/cache:       5805       6174
Swap:         5119          0       5119
```

As we can see, on both servers, limit_maxbytes was not reached. Only about 600MB was used at both the places. However on server 2, free memory dipped to as low as 100 mb. Now I know that cached is 5.8 GB and that linux could free that memory for running processes. But it looks like that didn't happen and seeing memory reaching critical level, memcached started evicting items.

Or is there any other reason? When exactly does linux free up cache memory? Is 100 mb of free ram is still not critical enough for linux to free up cache? Please help me understanding why such an even occured.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memcached eviction when cache is 40% full](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089889/memcached-eviction-when-cache-is-40-full)

Comment: where do I check slabs? It is not shown in memcached statistics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'slabs' refer to how Memcached allocates memory. Rather than a complex exact-match,it puts your data into a close-enough (slightly larger) piece of memory within the server. This means that it will frequently 'waste' memory that isn't storing your data.

You can tweak how big each potential slot is though when you start the memcached server with the factor (-f) and the initial chunk-size (-s) options. How you set those, depends on the mix of sizes you are storing in cache.

Comment: Some of the chunk sizes were in thousands and some of them were in hundreds of thousands. And there were 8 slabs. Two of which were completely unused. Others were full. Is this the issue you are talking about? And if so, how do I tackle this? There is another loaded instance already running. Could that create this problem?