# How to list all Memcachier's keys on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, memcached

Is it possible to list all memcachier keys of a Rails app? My app used just 3 keys and there are more than 30 on Memcachier app's page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this script: https://gist.github.com/bkimble/1365005
And we can used in our apps~

Answer (score -1):

You can't list all keys in memcached. memcached is a cache, not a database– if you need to consistently retrieve all keys, then memcached is probably not the tool you want to use.

With that in mind, 2 things:

- It's actually possible to retrieve the first meg or so of keys: http://www.darkcoding.net/software/memcached-list-all-keys/ . Your prod server should not depend on this.
- You could setup a system where you keep a key in memcached (named for example `index`), that has for its value a list of all the keys stored. Every time you're adding/deleting a key, you would also update `index`'s list of keys. You can just retrieve `index` to get a list of all the keys. However, keep in mind that [memcached can evict keys before they expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868256/memcached-eviction-prior-to-key-expiry), so your app shouldn't rely on this technique for critical stuff.