# Zero evictions memcached, but items still disappear

Tags: memcached

Items stored in Memcached seem to disappear without reason (TTL: 86400 but sometimes gone within 60s). However there's enough free space, and stats give zero evictions.

The items that get lost seem to be the larger items. They seem to disappear after adding some other big items. Could it be the case "The slab" for larger items is full and items are being evicted without being reported?

Memcached version 1.4.5.

Comment: Are you ever able to retrieve those items? How predictable are the disappearances? Can you write a code snippet that exactly reproduces the issue?

Comment: Are you ever able to retrieve those items?
Yes, sometimes I can retrieve them for a long period of time and sometimes it's gone in under 60s.
How predictable are the disappearances?
Totally unpredictable.
Can you write a code snippet that exactly reproduces the issue?

Comment: I can't write code that reproduces the issue. I think it has to do with the slab being full and not with the code. I'd like to get verified that items can be thrown out before there time without being an eviction (Which is unlikely, but the only thing I can come up with).

Answer (score 0):

Keys can get evicted before their expiration in memcached; this is a side effect of how memcached handles memory ([see this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868256/memcached-eviction-prior-to-key-expiry)).

If the items you are storing are large enough that this is becoming a problem, memcached may be the wrong tool for the task you are trying to perform. You essentially have 2 practical options in this scenario:

- break down the data you're trying to cache in smaller chunks
- if this isn't feasible for any reason, you will have to use some sort of permanent storage, the nature of which will be dependent on the nature of data you're trying to store (choices would include redis, mongodb, SQL database, filesystem, etc.)

Comment: But memcached is reporting 0 evictions. I'm having the same issue.