# Is it a good idea to store in cache a dict of my app's cache

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

When client make a POST, I need to delete all data modified by this request.

My memcached keys are hashed, so I can't find it by prefix. The only solution I found is to store a dict in DB or in cache, and I prefer in cache.

Do you think following ideas are good:

- Store a dict/list of cache keys ?
- To use cache or db for this function ?
- It's really stable solution, in logical and performance ?
- Maybe use a second cache for make it ?

Thanks to all.

**Edit:**

I want to store a dict as following:

```
{
  'subject1': ['key1','key2'],
  'subject2': ['key3','key3']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give you a satisfying answer without knowing the specifics of your application. With that in mind...

This can be an acceptable solution; however keep in mind that [objects can be evicted from memcached before their expiry date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868256/memcached-eviction-prior-to-key-expiry), in which case you'd lose your key index.

Depending on your specific use case, this limitation can be acceptable or not.

An approach that may serve you better is to be clever about how your name your keys; for example, if your application deals with books, you could cache various data under names such as `book.<id>.author`, `book.<id>.title`, etc. This way, if you need to invalidate all the data for the book with id 42, you could just generate all the cache names you need to invalidate (`book.42.author`, `book.42.title`, etc.) and delete those.

Comment: Thk for your answer, For give an example: I wanna store data computed from model instances. And if models change, clear the cache only for it.

Comment: If there's a one to one mapping between a model instance and the computed data, naming your keys in a fashion similar to my book example above will probably serve your purpose :)